# GoogleMobileAds file not found

Tags: ios, admob

I tried to remove and add the Google framework again but I still receive the same error.

[image]

Comment: erro Image here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/wveTk.jpg

Comment: add framework search path in Xcode build settings. Drag parent folder of GoogleMobileAds to framework search path window

Comment: thanks , it's worked after I download new sdk files from google